# What is the proper way in ColdFusion to return a Query object from Java?

Tags: coldfusion

We are using Java to call a web service to deliver a set of data back to ColdFusion.  What is the proper way to get the data from Java into a ColdFusion query object?

I see that there is a Query object interface in the Java CFX api but can not tell how to instantiate a new one.

Comment: If you invoke the method and dump the variable, what does it look like?  Also, why don't you simply call the web service from ColdFusion?

Comment: @DanBracuk I would love to call the Web Service from CF but I have never been successful in negotiating the Axis version problem.  I'm not sure what method you are suggestion I invoke.  I simply have some data in Java that I would like to put into a query object before returning it to CF.

Comment: What issue? Do you mean the web service is Axis2 and you are using CF9?

Comment: I believe that is the case @Leigh. We are on CF9.  I have not tried to debug it in a long time.  Essentially I have never been able to get CF to interact with a non trivial web service.  The one we are attempting to interact with is Exchange Web Services 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a CFX tag, try the [addQuery method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-5e4a.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e67) in the Response object

```
theResponse.addQuery(String name, String[] columns)
```

**Update:**

They may have added new interop functionality since the last I checked, but .. the only pure java method I am aware of is using the undocumented internal classes. If you already have a java [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) you could create a query object ie [`coldfusion.sql.QueryTable`](http://www.zrinity.com/developers/mx/undocumentation/query.cfm) using:

```
QueryTable query = new QueryTable(yourResultSet);
```

Another option is to instantiate the query object with the basics (row count, column names, etcetera). `coldfusion.sql.QueryTable(int rowCount, String columnNames[])` Then populated it manually, one row at a time.

Comment: (Condensed comments) Well I know some web services can be tricky. Hard to say whether using an intermediary java class is the best option without knowing more about the web service. See my updated response above.

Comment: I believe this is the only way to go.  Unfortunately, it looks like you can't actually populate the query one row at a time.  I keep getting UnsupportedOperation exceptions when trying to set/write.

Comment: Hm.. the last time I worked with query objects from java in ACF, it was via a legacy CFX ;-) I would have to check and see if there are any work arounds. Though not as simple, what about returning the results as an array of structures ie `java.util.List<java.util.Map>`? Then simply loop through the array in CF, or if you prefer, loop and convert it to a query object.

Comment: Yes, @Leigh that is what I did in the end.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was going to say you *might* be able to misuse the `com.allaire.cfx.DebugQuery` class, but ... that is a bit hackish. Honestly, what you ended up with is a simpler and more solid approach to the problem IMO.

Comment: Yep, tried that too! It implements the Query interface but it is not a true "query" object. It causes CFDUMP to crash on a COLUMNLIST reference.

Comment: Okay, now it has become a challenge of beating the CF server ;-) Looks like there is public constructor for `QueryTable` which accepts a cfx `Query` object. What happens if you use that constructor? (I still think `List<Map>` is a better way to go, but you have got me curious).